# Nhibernate With Clause Usage

Tags: nhibernate, criteria-api

I am trying to reproduce a query using the Nhibernate Criteria API and cannot work out how to add a criteria clause that allows me to compare two values from different tables.

The best trivial example I could come up with....

```
SELECT e.LastName
FROM Employee e
JOIN Chair c ON c.ChairId = e.ChairId
WHERE e.Weight > c.MaxLoad
```

My basic Nhibernate criteria

```
ICriteria criteria = base.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee));
criteria.CreateAlias("Employee.Chairid", "Chair", JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

One overload of create alias has an additional parameter of "withClause" which seems to be the suggested way to achieving this but for the life of me I cannot find an example of the syntax I would need to achieve this.

I think I need something along the lines of ...

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Ge("Employee.Weight", "Chair.MaxLoad"));
```

but this obviously doesn't work as the second parameter will be processed as a string value.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var employeeNames = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee))
    .CreateAlias("Chair", "c") // InnerJoin is implied
    .Add(Restrictions.GtProperty("Weight", "c.MaxLoad"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("LastName"))
    .List<string>();
```

The `Restrictions.XxProperty()` constraints are what you are looking for, which compare two properties against each other.